# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20221207T170935" in ical4j when specifying time zone Australia/Lord_Howe

Tags: java, timezone, date-format, ical4j

I am getting a parsing exception while I am trying the following code

```
    public class Timezone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        TimeZoneRegistry registry = TimeZoneRegistryFactory.getInstance().createRegistry();
        TimeZone tz;
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        final DateTimeFormatter ICS_DATE_FORMATTER =
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
        
        //tz = registry.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
        tz = registry.getTimeZone("Australia/Lord_Howe");
        DtStart dtstart;
        try {
        dtstart = new DtStart(now.format(ICS_DATE_FORMATTER),tz);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20221207T170935"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime.setTime(DateTime.java:418)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:325)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.DateProperty.setValue(DateProperty.java:137)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.DtStart.<init>(DtStart.java:146)
    at Timezone.main(Timezone.java:33)
```

I have used ical4j 3.0.19 jar and their dependency jar .

Its working for all the timezone except for the timezone "Australia/Lord_Howe".

I am expecting the Dtstart value as :

DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Lord_Howe:20221207T170935

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` is not being used. Your error comes from `java.text.DateFormat.parse`. Why are you mixing time APIs?

Comment: @g00se the `DateTimeFormatter` is used, but it's not the one that throws the `java.text.ParseException`, of course.

Comment: @deHaar. I'm not quite sure what your point is. We can both see that `DateTimeFormatter` appears in the code, obviously...

Comment: I am using ical4j because i am going to use it later to write iCalendar data streams .I tried above code for timezone (ex.Asia/Calcutta).I am getting expected result without any exception.

Comment: @g00se Just nitpicking because the line `dtstart = new DtStart(now.format(ICS_DATE_FORMATTER),tz);` definitely (and successfully) uses the `DateTimeFormatter`. You are right, the `Exception` is not thrown by it, it's not a `DateTimeParseException`…

Comment: OK. Actually, according to the Javadoc, it does support `java.time` so all should be well in theory. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: We should probably see the constructor of or the whole class `DtStart`.

Comment: Try `dtstart = new DtStart(now);`

Comment: @deHaar [`DtStart` dicumentation here](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mnode.ical4j/ical4j/3.2.7/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/property/DtStart.html).

Comment: @OleV.V. looks like a case for legacy compatibility: `new DtStart(Date.from(Instant.now()), tz)` might be working. No `LocalDateTime` needed…

Comment: And I have to correct my comment(s) (far) above: The `DateTimeFormatter` is used, but that's the problem: It's used to format the `LocalDateTime` as `String`, not for parsing it. That results in an invalid `String` representation, at least from the perspective of `DfStart`.

Comment: There is [a version 4.0.0-beta4](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mnode.ical4j/ical4j/latest/index.html) out where `DtStart` does support java.time. The OP would probably think twice before using it for production code immediately. @deHaar

Comment: A little debugging and experimentation revealed that the `DtStart` constructor that you are calling expects the time in UTC with a trailing `Z`, for example `20221207T060935Z` (tested with ical4j 3.2.7).

Comment: Its working for all the timezone except for the timezone "Australia/Lord_Howe".

Comment: Interesting! For me too it does work without `Z` with a couple time zones I tried, and with Australia/Lord_Howe only with `Z`.  Can’t tell what’s special about that zone. Well, yes, indeed I can: it’s the only time zone in the world that has 30 minutes summer time transitions (standard is 1 hour). But if that would cause ical4j to behave differently??!

Comment: A further observation: passing the value `20220707T233445` does work with Australia/Lord_Howe. So maybe it only fails with summer time (DST)?? It’s beginning to look like a bug in ical4j to me. I searched a bit for a description of one, but found nothing, though. And then the value mentioned fails with time zone Antarctica/Troll (a time zone that has 2 hours summer time adjustment). :-(

Comment: yeah correct problem with summer time(DST) for Australia/Lord_howe
@Ole V.V. Seems like a bug in ical4j .

Comment: It seems that it should be possible to [create a new issue on GitHub here](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/issues).

Answer (score 1):

No need for parsing:

```
package com.technojeeves.ical;

import java.util.List;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.TimeZone;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.TimeZoneRegistry;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.TimeZoneRegistryFactory;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.DtStart;

import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ParameterList;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Parameter;

import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.parameter.TzId;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DtStart<LocalDateTime> localDtStart = new DtStart<>(now);
        System.out.println(localDtStart);
        ParameterList params = new ParameterList(List.of(new TzId("Australia/Lord_Howe")));
        DtStart<ZonedDateTime> zonedDtStart = new DtStart<>(params, ZonedDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(zonedDtStart);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
DTSTART:20221208T150844

DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Lord_Howe:20221209T020844
```

So far I haven't got the source of the version I'm using (4.0.0-beta4). Yes, it's a beta, but I suspect they might have supported `Temporal` for some time. Actually I discover that all versions 4.x support it.

My guess is that they'll fix the above ctor in time to act on `ZonedDateTime` as the initializing type, since, at the moment, if that's used, `DtStart.toString` shows no sign of the zone.

Comment: Interesting. Which version of ical4j are you using? OP is using 3.0.19.

Comment: @goose I am using 3.0.19 version of ical4j

Comment: Yes, I know. Obviously the later the version you can use, the likelier it is to support `java.time`